# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS windowing system

Tags: 22.04, xorg, wayland

Hello everyone help me please.Ubuntu 22.04.2 lts is x11 default in windowing system?Because it shows as x11 on setting > about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The default windowing system in Ubuntu 22.04 is Wayland.

Both X and Wayland are included, and most users can switch between then during login. The selection is on the password screen.

The system will remember your selection, and will continue to use the same during future logins until you select differently.

Some hardware is incompatible with Wayland. Those systems do not present a choice, and will only run X.

Comment: Thanks for reply.this (setting icon)section can't found on password screen right conor

Comment: Addressed in the last paragraph of the answer.